# Creating a specific index based in 2 variables

Tags: sas

Supose i want to calculate a new variable on SAS that is a index of which order a client made(first, second, and so on).
I have two original variables: Client ID and date of purchase, something on these lines (i have other variables too, but they won't change the new variable):

```
CLIENT_ID     DATE_OF_PURCHASE     ITEM 
12345         11NOV2013            A
12345         11NOV2013            B
12345         11NOV2013            C
12345         22DEC2013            A
67890         17OCT2013            A
67890         17OCT2013            B
88888         07NOV2013            A
88888         28NOV2013            A
88888         28NOV2013            C
```

The new var would look like this:

```
CLIENT_ID     DATE_OF_PURCHASE     ITEM     ORDER 
12345         11NOV2013            A        1
12345         11NOV2013            B        1
12345         11NOV2013            C        1
12345         22DEC2013            A        2
67890         17OCT2013            A        1
67890         17OCT2013            B        1
88888         07NOV2013            A        1
88888         28NOV2013            A        2
88888         28NOV2013            C        2
```

That is, the client 12345 made one order at 11NOV2013, buying 3 items, and another at 22DEC2013, buying one item. And so on.

Is there any simple way of creating this new variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use FIRST. with BY group to determine how to set the order.

```
data have;
informat date_of_purchase DATE9.;
input CLIENT_ID     DATE_OF_PURCHASE     ITEM $;
datalines;
12345         11NOV2013            A
12345         11NOV2013            B
12345         11NOV2013            C
12345         22DEC2013            A
67890         17OCT2013            A
67890         17OCT2013            B
88888         07NOV2013            A
88888         28NOV2013            A
88888         28NOV2013            C
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
by client_id date_of_purchase;
if first.client_id then ordernum=0;
if first.date_of_purchase then ordernum+1;
run;
```